# How to insert image in xhtml?

Tags: image, xhtml

I have saved the image in img folder under WebContent in eclipse. How to insert the image into xhtml code?

```
<img border="0" src="/WebContent/img/si.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, the image is probably in another directory or of the wrong type. I mean, the code should work.

Comment: It won't validate though. There are three problems with it. But let's solve the problem of the image not showing up first.

Comment: @MrLister I have saved the si.jpg inisde img folder and placed under WebContent in eclipse. So I wonder how the directory should be

Comment: What matters is where the WebContent directory is relatively to the location of the xhtml file.

Answer (score -2):

XHTML5. Do *not* use the `border` attribute on an image element, it's invalid/legacy. Use CSS with a selector to choose either the specific image or a set of images using a CSS class. Not sure if you're serving the correct media type/mime for XHTML5, the XML parser is superior though if you're not serving the correct media type/mime you'll get stuck with the lazy HTML parser instead. You can also use JavaScript's [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method if you don't want to add the image to the end of the element after all of it's child elements.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'],'application/xhtml+xml'))
{
 header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8');
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
}
else
{
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Moderation</title>
<script defer="true" type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function image(img)
{
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 img.setAttribute('alt','Alternative Text');
 img.setAttribute('src',img);
 document.getElementById('example').appendChild(img);}

window.onload = function(e)
{
 //Anonymous function for onload event allows you to call multiple functions.
 //Always have event handlers at the end (bottom) of your JavaScript.
 //Never put script elements in the body, use the defer or async attributes.
 image('images/si.jpg');
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="example"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is effectively a series of comments, not an answer. You've written the code, but not in a way that addresses the problem of the image not showing up. As the comments on the question point out, there is nothing demonstrated in the question that could cause the problem.

Comment: "the XML parser is superior though" — Really? Last time I heard anything about it, the HTML parser was superior because the browser vendors optimised it. Since hardly anyone uses XHTML, they don't invest effort into the XML parser.

Comment: Your XHTML is invalid. `true` is not a valid value for `defer` which can't appear on a `<script>` without a `src`.

Comment: Go learn to use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) instead of making personal attacks. I stand by my previous comment.